# Why are there gaps and clusters in coronavirus case numbers?

Tags: statistics

Although the coronavirus pandemic is of course a drama and a tragedy on a human as well as an economical level, it does provide interesting material for statistical analysis.

Looking at the case numbers per country ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgylp3Td1Bw) for example), I noticed a tendency for certain small sets of countries (such as Italy and Spain) to form clusters with very similar case numbers, whereas the numerical gaps between these clusters are relatively wide. Most spectacularly so between the US and the rest of the world.

Is this merely a coincidence particular to this specific outbreak, or is there a reasonably simple statistical model that would account for the numbers to distribute themselves as they do? I realize that in the actual world the number of recorded cases in a country depends on many factors, such as population size and density, testing criteria and methodology, date of first infection, etc. But I'd be interested to hear whether a simpler model would reproduce the case distribution among countries.

Comment: I suspect it's just a coincidence that Italy and Spain have very similar numbers. I don't see any other of these clusters. There are a lot of factors that impact the number of cases in a specific country ... it seems unlikely that these factors would all conspire to make some kind of nice clustering. More likely, it is our natural human cognitive bias to see patterns, even when there are none.

Comment: Three issues to consider: (1)  Countries are of vastly different sizes, so not surprising US > Italy. (2) Methods of managing spread of the virus are hugely different. Stern measures in China that might not be possible in US. Within the US, California was early to mandate 'stay at home except for buying food and Rx' rules. Until just recently some US states have largely ignored mitigation. Responses across the EU have varied almost as much as across US states. Some kinds of mitigation short of military law _are_ effective. (3) Different pop densities: High rises, subways promote contagion.